# XML DTD for downloadable stories

Tags: xml

I want to make sure that I am writing the code correctly and fully understand what is needed. My biggest concern is what tags to use, (`?` `*` `|` etc.)

> 5. The element stories
>      5.1.  The element stories contains 0 or more story elements.
> 6. The element story
>      6.1.  The element story has an enumerated attribute updated that can only have the values true, false, or unknown. The default is true.
>      Represents whether or not the story was updated since the last time
>      the feed was downloaded.
>      6.2.  The element story’s first element is the url element. Must appear exactly once. A link to the story.
>      6.3.  The element story’s second element is the title element. Must appear exactly once.
>      6.4.  The element story’s third element is the preview element. Must appear exactly once. A short introduction to the story. Usually, about
>      1 sentence.
>      6.5.  The element story’s element content is optional, but if present, appears no more than once. The story. Some sites allow the story text
>      in feeds, some don’t. That is why it is optional
>      6.6.  The element story’s element video is optional, but if present, appears no more than once. A link to an optional video.
>      6.6.1.    The order of the elements content and video does not matter. If both are present, content can be first or video can be first.
>      6.7.  The element story’s last element publication-date is optional, but if present, appears no more than once and must be the last
>      element. The date the story was published.
> 7. The element title
>      7.1.  The element title can contain text

### My code:

```
<!ELEMENT stories (stories*)>
<!ELEMENT story (update true|false, url?, title?, preview?, content?, video?, publication-date?>
<!ELEMENT title >
```

Comment: Do you know why you have to use DTDs instead of the more modern and more expressive XSD? Do you know the difference between an _element_ and an _attribute_?

Comment: Was part of a class assignment, and have to write it in a dtd, i have the XML for them alredy, just not fully understanding the dtd.

Comment: IMO this question is quite similar to [your previous one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/233092/) in that it seems to lack sufficient code context for a meaningful review.

Comment: Yes this is a code i did and turn out to be wrong, now I am trying in small sections to see what i been doing wrong. the dtd it self is 24 question.

Comment: There is not enough code here for a review, just like your earlier question. Please *fix* a question instead of deleting and re-posting it. We can help you, if you tell us what you're doing and if the code is working as intended. If the code is producing incorrect results, the code is not ready for a review. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

There's an unmatched `(` in the declaration of the contents of `story`.  I recommend that you actually test the DTD using a validating parser such as OpenSP before posting code for review.

6.1 is not satisfied: you have declared content for `story` but no attributes.

6.2-6.4 are not satisfied: the `url`, `title` and `preview` elements must each appear **exactly once**.

6.6.1 is not satisfied: you only allow `content` before `video` and not `video` before `content`.

7.1 is not satisfied, because `title` has been declared as an empty element.

Comment: "The element stories contains 0 or more story elements" . To write this i have to say (stories*), is the * right to use in this situation. And "The element title can contain text" do i type title (text) ?? this are the questions i am wondering

Comment: The requirement 7.1 says `title` can contain text, rather than `title` can contain a `text` element; my reading is that you're expected to declare as having Parsed Character Data content rather than element content.  But that's something you ought to clarify with whoever gave you the requirements.  I'm not convinced this is ready for review until you can answer some of your own questions...